# How to hide bars on a stacked bar chart in C3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a stacked bar chart made with `C3.js` which uses the following code to be generated:

```
stacked_bar_chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#stacked_bar_chart_container',
        data: {
            columns: [
               ["Critical", 446, 863], 
               ["High", 1160, 2301],
               ["Medium", 3106, 8258], 
               ["Low", 277, 119], 
               ["Informational", 7374, 23240]
            ],
            type: 'bar',
            groups: [
                ['Low', 'Medium', 'Informational', 'High', 'Critical', 'Unknown']
            ],
        },
        grid: {
            y: {
                lines: [{ value: 0 }]
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: ["Remediated", "Unconfirmed"] // Notice the x-axis has categories
            },
            y: {
                label: 'Number of Findings'
            }
        },       
    });
```

I am trying to make it so that at the click of a button, I am able to hide the bar called `Remediated` from the graph. I have tried to unload it by doing the following:

```
stacked_bar_chart.unload("Remediated");
```

but this has no effect, and I am pretty sure it is because I am using `type: 'category'` for the x-axis. I would prefer to not have to unload the data anyways so that later on I can re-display the bar as needed without retrieving the data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research in the `C3.js` reference page, I think that there is no easy API function for this to be accomplished, so I have come up with my own tested implementation of this feature that I am currently using.

Firstly, with the way that I do it I am keeping track of three separate global variables which will hold the data currently in the chart and also will hold the data we remove from it. This is the way I decided to choose because the data for my chart is coming from a web resource, so it would be inefficient to keep making AJAX calls and refreshing the data every time a category is added or removed.

```
// Our three new variables
var removed_from_stacked_bar = {};
var stacked_bar_categories = ["Remediated", "Unconfirmed"];
var stacked_bar_data = [
               ["Critical", 446, 863], 
               ["High", 1160, 2301],
               ["Medium", 3106, 8258], 
               ["Low", 277, 119], 
               ["Informational", 7374, 23240]
            ];

function initialize_stacked_bar_chart(data, categories) {
    stacked_bar_chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#stacked_bar_chart_container',
        data: {
            columns: data, // Coming from the parameter
            type: 'bar',
            groups: [
                ['Low', 'Medium', 'Informational', 'High', 'Critical', 'Unknown']
            ],
        },
        grid: {
            y: {
                lines: [{ value: 0 }]
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: categories // Coming from the parameter
            },
            y: {
                label: 'Number of Findings'
            }
        },       
    });
}

initialize_stacked_bar_chart(stacked_bar_data, stacked_bar_categories);
```

Now I wrote a function called `update_stacked_bar_chart()` which has a `category` parameter in order to remove / add the `category` that is passed in from the chart whenever it is called.

```
function update_stacked_bar_chart(category) {
    var categoryIndex = stacked_bar_categories.indexOf(category);
    var removed_values = [];
    if (categoryIndex != -1) { // Removing the item since it exists in the bar chart's categories
        stacked_bar_categories.splice(categoryIndex, 1); // Removing the category name from the bar chart's category list
        stacked_bar_data.forEach(function (item, index) {
            var temp = item.splice(categoryIndex + 1, 1); // Removing the value this category held (in-place) in the sublist for each severity
            removed_values.push(temp); // Pushing each removed value into the array of removed values (in order from Critical, High, Medium, Low, Informational).
        });
        removed_from_stacked_bar[category] = removed_values;
    } else { // Re-adding the item if it was not found in the current chart's categories
        stacked_bar_categories.push(category); // Adding the category name to the bar chart's category list
        removed_from_stacked_bar[category].forEach(function (item, index) {
            stacked_bar_data[index].push(item); // Adding the value for each severity into the respective severity list 
        });
        delete removed_from_stacked_bar[category];
    }
    initialize_stacked_bar_chart(stacked_bar_data, stacked_bar_categories); // Remaking the bar chart with the new data and categories.
}
```

This function will allow you to toggle any category from your bar chart every time it is called. You can attach it to an event listener so that it is called as you need it.

Here is an example of how it can be used to toggle bars as it is called:

```
update_stacked_bar_chart("Remediated"); // Removes the "Remediated" bar
update_stacked_bar_chart("Remediated"); // Re-adds the "Remediated" bar
update_stacked_bar_chart("Remediated"); // Removes the "Remediated" bar
update_stacked_bar_chart("Unconfirmed"); // Removes the "Unconfirmed" bar
update_stacked_bar_chart("Remediated"); // Re-adds the "Remediated" bar
update_stacked_bar_chart("Unconfirmed"); // Re-adds the "Unconfirmed" bar
```